# How to clear this . Class Cast exception in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-applications

```
package com.blacksheep;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BlackSheepApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BlackSheepApplication.class, args);
    }
}


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getInitialUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.<init>(Restarter.java:138)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:537)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartedEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:45)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.started(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.blacksheep.BlackSheepApplication.main(BlackSheepApplication.java:11)
```

each time I run the main file I am getting this exception. Can anyone help?

This was working an hour ago. Just updated the code with git pull and nothing works now

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7226

I was trying with  java 9. Change to java 8. Works like charm now